# Filtering varnishlog v4

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to filter varnishlog (version 4) to only show requests to certain URLs or certain IP addresses.  All of the examples online are for version 3.  Version 4 seems to use a different method of filtering and I can't find any documentation on it. Is it possible to filter this way?

Comment: did you try `man varnishlog` and/or `varnishlog help`?

Comment: Of course, it lists being able to query using the -q option but doesn't say how to use that option

Comment: The man page `vls-query` should describe the query language

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the tags described here: http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Examining_Varnish_Server_s_Output.html#query-language

By example:

```
varnishlog -n varnish-instance-name -q 'ReqURL ~ "^/search" and ReqStart ~ "^127.0.0.1"'
```