# varnishlog - how to log only certain paths?

Tags: varnish, regex

I want to log all requests to static pages in a certain directory via `varnishlog`.

This is what I have tried:

```
varnishlog -c -q "ReqURL ~ '.*version15.*'"
```

Works - but I want to limit it further.

```
varnishlog -c -q "ReqURL ~ '.*static.*version15.*'"
```

Does not work.

```
varnishlog -c -q "ReqURL ~ '/static/version15/tpl/my_template.html"
```

Does not work.

I have checked [Filtering varnishlog v4](https://serverfault.com/questions/696174/filtering-varnishlog-v4/729205), https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vsl-query.html - but was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `varnishlog -c -q "ReqURL ~ '/static/version15/tpl/my_template.html"` isn't working is because you forgot the *single quote at the end that closes your string*.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Query expression error:
Unterminated string (Pos 49)
ReqURL ~ '/static/version15/tpl/my_template.html
```

This is the command that should work for you:

```
varnishlog -c -q "ReqURL ~ '/static/version15/tpl/my_template.html'"
```

I've simulated the call on a test setup, and it works fine.

The command you're trying to run, matches an explicit URL, but your question was actually about matching static files in a directory. I suggest using something like this:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '/static/version15/tpl/.*\.html'"
```

Comment: Thank you! I can actually not reproduce it anymore, because I do not have any varnish system at hand at the moment. I also cannot tell if the missing quote was a copy&paste mistake on the way to serverfault, or if I made that mistake on the server. I should have noticed that error message, but who knows. Your answer sounds very reasonable; thank you so much!